# How can I "globalize" struct methods?

Tags: c++, class, global, using

I have a struct/class and i want to call some (or all) of its methods globally (without writing class_name::func_name() every time. I don't know what to replace on the `using namespace foo;` line. I want foo to remain a struct/class, i don't want to change the struct itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo
{
    struct point
    {
        ll x, y;
    };

    inline void say_hi()
    {
        printf("hi\n");
    }
};

// using namespace foo; // this obviously doesn't work, foo is not a namespace
// using foo:foo;                           // none of them work
// using foo::point(); using foo::say_hi(); //

int main ()
{
    point p;
    say_hi();

    return 0;
}
```

The 3 lines that are on comments, won't compile. Is there any way to abuse `using`, or is there any other keyword for that?

Comment: If you want free functions then make free functions. If there is no point in knowing the function belongs to a class or struct or doesn't require an instance to call then why is it a member?

Comment: Just move `say_hi` to the top level. Problem solved.

Comment: Consider to think again you design, seems to me you're after the controversial singleton antipattern [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6jG39Tden)

Answer (score 1):

Your struct method is **non-static**, so it is *required* to be called on an *instance* of your struct, ie:

```
foo f;
f.say_hi();
```

You CAN'T globalize it the way you want (even if there was a syntax for that. which there isn't).

In your example, `say_hi()` doesn't access any data members of the struct, so there is really no good reason for it to be a method of the struct at all.  It should be a free-standing function instead, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void say_hi()
{
    printf("hi\n");
}

int main ()
{
    say_hi();

    return 0;
}
```

Or, at least, as a `static` method of the struct (but that introduces the very syntax you are trying to avoid, but WHY do you want to avoid it?):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo
{
    ...

    static void say_hi()
    {
        printf("hi\n");
    }
};

int main ()
{
    foo::say_hi();

    return 0;
}
```

I suppose you could use a macro to hide the unwanted syntax, but that is not much clearer and certainly not good practice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo
{
    ...

    static void say_hi()
    {
        printf("hi\n");
    }
};

#define foo_say_hi() foo::say_hi()

int main ()
{
    foo_say_hi();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method without an instance of the class, you need to make it **static**:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
using ll = long long;
struct foo
{
    struct point
    {
        ll x, y;
    };

    static void say_hi()
    {
        printf("hi\n");
    }
};

int main ()
{
    foo::point p;
    foo::say_hi();

    return 0;
}
```

Try it online: https://godbolt.org/z/cPGzhTTv4